# Variables and template loading

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a template which I want to fill with my variables. Some parts are optional, so I also have some variables in my code, which define, if that part of the template will be rendered. The troubeling part of the template looks like this:

```
{% if current_task_interactive_has_translated_answers %}
    "acceptedAnswers": [],
{% else %}
    "acceptedAAnswers": [], 
{% endif %}
```

At the start, I set the variable current_task_interactive_has_translated_answers = True, but it somehow evaluates to False (I would like it to evaluate to True), even though **I dont reasign it**.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You should show the part where you set that variable and how you pass it to the template.

Comment: Yup it sounds like you did not pass current_task_interactive_has_translated_answers into your template context.